# How can I pass text to sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, vectorization

Passing sequence of strings (text data) in a `dict` looking like:

```
dataset = {
    0: 'adadba eefe', 
    1: 'blabla lablab', 
    2: 'etcetc', 
    3: 'zyxzyxz'
}
```

to `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(dataset)` does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whats the semantics of your dictionary, i.e. what do the keys mean and how do they relate to the text? Do you want to keep the keys when vectorizing? If so, how?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the syntax of the function, but I am just trying to vectorize a corpus of strings and get a matrix, each row would be a separate string identified by the key (number in the dictionary) and each column represents numbers of particular token occurrence in the strings. The strings in the question are just for example, actually they consist of several normal words each and there about 400 of them. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer` accepts a list of strings as input, so if the keys in your `dict` simply represent an index, the easiest way to get a TF-IDF representation of your corpus would be the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

dataset = {
    0: 'adadba eefe', 
    1: 'blabla lablab', 
    2: 'etcetc', 
    3: 'zyxzyxz'
}     

vec = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(dataset.values()) # X is a sparse matrix containing the TF-IDF representations of your input corpus
```

The rows of `X` will follow your indices in the `dict`, e.g. row 0 will contain the TF-IDF representation of the sentence `'adadba eefe'`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My mistake was passing (dataset) instead of (dataset.values()), the rest of the code was the same.

Comment: No problem :), would you mind accepting the answer if it solves your problem?